# c++ partial template specialization with requires statement: error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' from class Bar<T> without definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Consider the following code which attempts to implement a partial specialization of `class Bar`. In the first case, the `foo` member function is defined inline and in the second case out of line. The out of line definition produces a compile error which I cannot figure out:

`error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' from class 'Bar<T>' without definition`

```
template<class T>
struct Bar;

template<class T>
requires std::is_same_v<T, int>
struct Bar<T> {
    int foo(T a) {
        return a + 5;
    }
};

template<class T>
requires std::is_same_v<T, double>
struct Bar<T> {
    double foo(T a);
};

template<class T>
requires std::is_same_v<T, double>
double Bar<T>::foo(T a) {
    return a + 5;
};
```

I am using clang-11 with the c++20 compilation option. I am unsure if this is my misunderstanding, a feature or a bug. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also true for `clang` 10 to 13: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dK69T84v5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be clang bug. It was reported at https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50276.
Anyway GCC is fine